# How to query for a specific combination of nodes in Arango DB graph

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

I have a graph containing two vertex collections: Attraction (green) and Hotel (orange).

I want to query for a certain combination of Attractions and Hotels, such as the one given below:

```
Attraction (start vertex) ---> Attraction ---> Hotel
                                   |
                                   |
                                   v
                               Attraction
```

Graph has directed edges as shown.

The query I have now (below) gives any part of the above combination, instead of four nodes connected exactly as above.

```
FOR document IN Attraction FOR vertex, edge, path IN 1..2 OUTBOUND document GRAPH "LondonAttractionDB" 
FILTER path.vertices[0].entityTypes[0] == "Attraction" 
FILTER path.vertices[1].entityTypes[0] == "Attraction" 
FILTER path.vertices[2].entityTypes[0] == "Hotel" OR path.vertices[2].entityTypes[0] == "Attraction" 
RETURN path
```

[image]

Above query gives all **combinations containing two, three or four nodes** as shown above. How can I get only the results (**combinations of exactly four nodes**) shown within circles?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual result of your query? What does "gives all combinations" mean? Does it return paths with depth 1 that you don't want? Have you tried `2..2 OUTBOUND` since you seem to be interested in paths with depth 2 only?

Comment: I have edited the question. Query gives combinations of two, three or four nodes connected as above. I want combinations of exactly four nodes connected as above.

Comment: So the nodes at depth two (one attraction, one hotel) are supposed to be leaf nodes (no outgoing edges)? Otherwise there would be 4 matches (red circles).

Comment: @CoDEmanX Nodes at depth two are not necessarily leaf nodes. They could have connected nodes as well.

Comment: I edited the question to include all the desired results within the current result I get. What I need is to find paths from an attraction, to another attraction that has both a hotel and an attraction near it. But the result gives if either a hotel or an attraction is near the second attraction. How can I get the result I want as described above?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you had duplication in the result?
If yes then you can use `DISTINCT` in the return value.
Otherwise, try BFS unique vertices and unique edges:

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/traversals/

Comment: Using min depth 2 (`2..2`) or using bfs and unique vertices (`OPTIONS {bfs:"true", uniqueVertices:"global"}` and `OPTIONS {bfs:"true", uniqueVertices:"path"}`) did not work. What I want is to get paths going exactly up to depth 2 and terminate path from there, so that the result will include only the paths shown within red circles.

Comment: Well Try following. 
for depth 1..2 you can change depth whatever you want

"for vertex, edge, path in 1..2 outbound 'source_Attractionid' Attraction 
options { bfs:true, uniqueVertices: 'global', uniqueEdges: 'path' }
FILTER path.vertices[0].entityTypes[0] == "Attraction" 
FILTER path.vertices[1].entityTypes[0] == "Attraction" 
FILTER path.vertices[2].entityTypes[0] == "Hotel" OR path.vertices[2].entityTypes[0] == "Attraction" 
RETURN path"

Comment: It still gives several combinations, but different from the results above.

Comment: can you share your query and json result.